# Can I plug dj gear to Pilot 2013?

Tags: electrical, battery

The touring pilot 2013 can provide 650 watts, and has a 115V outlet.

But can it handle a good 2-3 hours of djing or would it kill the battery? 
All together the dj gear may consume up to 150 watts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it - Car betteries are designed for short bursts of high current (i.e. starting the engine), not prolonged discharge of that sort.

If you want to use a car to power equipment, it is generally better to have a second 'leisure' battery fitted, with a split-charging system. Leisure batteries are designed for that kind of usage, and you have the added advantage that, if you leave it on for too long and run the battery right down, you can still start the car on the main battery!

Such systems are a common fitment to 4x4s for camping use, so a decent 4x4 supplier in your area should be able to advise you and provide the required equipment.